# Is there a way to iterate over a userdata, like pairs and ipairs do with a table?

Tags: lua

Is there a function to iterate over the entries in a userdata value? I'm trying to list every field and its value in some userdata variable, just like `pairs` would do:

```
local function list_entries ( obj )
    for k, v in pairs ( obj ) do
        print ( k .. ": " .. tostring ( v ) )
    end
end
```

`pairs` doesn't work for userdata, so is there a solution to this?

Comment: there is no standard function. you would have to provide something that is tailored to your userdata object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua 5.2+ provides the `__pairs` and `__ipairs` metamethods. If a userdata provides them, then the corresponding Lua iterator will call them to get the iteration data. This means that the userdata must explicitly choose to provide iteration support; it cannot be *forced* on it.

After all, userdata doesn't actually contain anything (at least, as far as Lua is concerned). All of its Lua functionality comes through the metamethods it provides. `data.val` only works because the userdata has an `__index` metamethod that can take the string `"val"`. Iteration is no different; if the userdata doesn't provide it, you can't do it.

In earlier versions of Lua, you can replace the existing `pairs` and `ipairs` functions with something that does what the 5.2+ versions do: look for the metamethods and use them if they're available. Of course, this can only be done from C, since only C code can get the metatable for userdata.

Comment: I see. But if I don't own the userdata source code and if it doesn't provide __pairs or __ipairs metamethods then this can't be done?